# Styles don't not work on production but works on a local

Tags: css, deployment, styles, tailwind-css

Doesn't matter where i deploy (and build there), it's always same on every provider.

When i first build locally and then upload the build, it works.

**UPDATE**

Problem was probably with windows (my local build) not being case-sensitive but production build (linux) is.

And i had typo in tailwind.config.js purge: `['./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}', './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}']`
*components instead of Components*

Comment: move tailwindcss to dependencies

Comment: thank you very much for your comment, i did, but it didnt help, https://github.com/rastislavuhrin/tatiho-portfolio/blob/main/package.json here is the site ladenie-klavirov.sk

Comment: try this: `purge: ['./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}', './Components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],`

Comment: Components with uppercase C

Comment: YES!! thank you   i thought purge is just an optimization for production, anyway i can't upvote your answer, why did you write comment and not and answer?

Comment: because I can't explain why this is working on dev but not in production :)

Comment: nvm, thank you and good luck ^^

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.